# How can I pass the model in jquery as a JSON variable?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On a MVC/Razor page, I have a view with a model where one element is list of another model.  That list is written to the view using a partial view.  So if the list has 3 elements, there are 3 rows on the view.  I want to send the value of the entire list using JSON so that I can carry out some calculations.  How can I pass the values of the model or the elements in the list part of the model to the controller using JSON?

So my page looks like this:

```
-------------------------
|                       |
| | ID |  | Price |     |
| | ID |  | Price |     |
| | ID |  | Price |     |
|                       |
-------------------------
```

I want to send every ID and price (a variable number of rows) to the controller using JSON to perform calculations.  Something like this:

```
 $("#btnCreateContract").click(function () {

    var url = '/CreateContract/CheckSalesSlips';

    $.getJSON(
        url
        ,
         {
           cashPrice: $("#txtCashDownPayment_rev").val()
           , salesSlip: model
         }
        , function (response)
        {
        status = response.status;
        }
       );

    return status;
});
```

The controller has a method like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CheckSalesSlips(string cashPrice, ModelSalesSlips salesSlips)
    {
        decimal total = 0.00M;
        foreach (var item in salesSlips)
        {
            total = total + item.Price;
        }

        if (total.ToString() != cashPrice) // Check that sales slip item equals the amount financed.
        {
            return Json(new { status = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { status = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    } // CheckSalesSlips
```

However, I'm getting a message saying model is not defined.  I also tried

```
salesSlip: '<%= Model.salesSlips %>'
```

and

```
salesSlip: '<%= Model %>'
```

and other variations, but the saleSlip variable is always blank when it gets to the controller.

If I had just one control (i.e. there was one price field) I could use the ID of the control to get the value.  In my case, however, I have a variable number of controls.

Can someone tell me how to pass a model through JSON in jquery?  If this isn't possible, how could I pass a variable number of control values to the controller?

If you've seen my previous posts, this is my first MVC project and I'm new to Razor, jquery, and JSON as well, so please go easy on me.  Thanks!

Here's some other code:

The main model for the page, ModelApplication.cs:

```
public class ModelApplication
{
    public int Id { get; set; 
    public List<ModelSalesSlip> salesSlips { get; set; }
}
```

The model for the elements in the list, ModelSalesSlip:

```
public class ModelSalesSlip
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Relevant parts of the view, CreateContract.Mobile.cshtml:

```
@model Models.ModelApplication
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateContract.Mobile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminMaster.Mobile.cshtml";
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id="formCreateContract", @class = "form-horizontal ", @commandname = "ModelApplication" }))
{
   @{
     foreach (var item in Model.salesSlips)
     {
       <tr>
      @{
         Html.RenderPartial("CreateContractPartial", item);
       }
      </tr>
     }
<input id="btnCreateContract" type="submit" value="Save" name="CreateContract" />
}
```

The partial view, CreateContractPartial.Mobile.cshtml:

```
<div class="editorRow">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("salesSlips"))
 {
    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ID, new { @class = "wide" })</td>
    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { @class = "wide" })</td>
 }
 </div>
```

Comment: this post should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102560/passing-model-from-view-to-controller-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to return all your items yet your POST method has parameter `ModelSalesSlips salesSlips` (i.e. one `ModelSalesSlips` item, not a collection).

You can use the `.serialize()` function to send all form control values back to the controller

```
var url = '@Url.Action("CheckSalesSlips", "CreateContract")'; // don't hardcode urls!
$("#btnCreateContract").click(function () {
  $.getJSON(url, $(form.serialize(), function(response) {
    ....
  });
});
```

and the controller method would be

```
public JsonResult CheckSalesSlips(string cashPrice, List<ModelSalesSlips> salesSlips)
```

You have not shown the input with `id="txtCashDownPayment_rev"`, but assuming it has `name="cashprice"` and is within the `<form>` tags, then its value will be bound to the parameter `cashPrice` in the method (but you really should be using a view model with an additional property for `decimal CashPrice { get; set; }` and use a strongly type helper to create the input, then post back to `public JsonResult CheckSalesSlips(YourViewModel model)`).

However, since you seem to be comparing the total of `decimal` value, then parameter `cashPrice` should be type of `decimal`, not `string`.

However all this seems an unnecessary waste of band width when you could easily perform this check on the client - something like

```
var total = 0;
$(.editorRow).each(function(index, item) {
  total += new Number($(this).find('input[type="text"]).last().val());
});
if (new Number($("#txtCashDownPayment_rev").val()) == total)
{
  ....
```

Comment: Thank you.  Really appreciate the code showing how to do this without going to the server; that will really help.