# Post dropdownlistfor model binding without reloading page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a "dynamic" page which contains a `dropdownlistfor`. When I select a value from the dropdown, the page, without redirecting, hides the old div which contained the old dropdown, and displays a new div (using JS .show() function) with a new dropdown that pulls data based on the value of the old dropdown.

My issue is that I don't know how to POST the value of the first dropdown to it's model without redirecting or reloading the page. I have tried this:

```
 $('#binRange_start_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Which doesn't call the setter function of my field in my model:

```
private String _BinRangeSelection;

    public String BinRangeSelection
    {
        get
        {
            return _BinRangeSelection;
        }

        set
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("testing");
            string[] rangeSplit = Regex.Split(value, " - ");
            foreach (IdentifiBINConfiguration ibc in IdentifiBINConfigs)
            {
                if (ibc.LowerRange == rangeSplit[0] && ibc.UpperRange == rangeSplit[1])
                {
                    IdentifiBINConfiguration = ibc;
                }
            }

            _BinRangeSelection = value;
        }
    }
```

And it also reloads the page.

Comment: Why not use an ajax call to a controller method?

Comment: @Pseudonym But how could I pass in the model to that call so the controller can modify the model? I thought that wasn't possible with JS.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18102625/2374987